# How to retrieve binarydata source of an image in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, image, binary-data

I want to get image preview before uploading any image in my asp.net webform. I am doing this by the following code. But after clicking Save button I want to upload the image to the server. In my codebehind I am getting src="" for `<img>`. What can I do to get the binarydata back to save my file.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMyImage(fileInput) {
        var files = fileInput.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var imageType = /image.*/;
            if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
                continue;
            }
            var link = $(fileInput).siblings('.thumb').attr('src');
            alert(link);
            var img = document.getElementById("thumbnil");
            img.file = file;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (aImg) {
                return function (e) {
                    aImg.src = e.target.result;
                };
            })(img);
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="showMyImage(this)" />
            <br />
            <img id="thumbnil" class="thumb" style="width: 20%; margin-top: 10px;" src="" alt="image" runat="server"/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Unnamed_Click"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</form>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: dont read the img-tag src-attribute, the client cant update it on server side and it wont be "post-back". use an input field or so

Comment: @winner_joiner :Then any other solution to get this done?

Comment: @winner_joiner: can you explain `use input field or so`?

Comment: look at my anwser below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***### Undated whole Answer ###***

**Option 1:**

dont read the img-tag src-attribute, the client cant update it on server side and it wont be "post-back". use an input field like this

```cs
<form...>
    ...
    <input class="image-data" type="hidden" id="imageString" runat="server" />
    ...
</form>
```

and in the Js-Code add this dataurl as value of this field.

```js
 ...
 reader.onload = (function (aImg) {
     return function (e) {
     aImg.src = e.target.result;
     //... add this, it's searches for the input-field, to be able to post the String to the Server
     $(".image-data").val(e.target.result);
 };
 ...
```

**Update:**

On the Server you can read the Data like this.

```cs
 string imageData = imageString.Value;
```

**Option 2:**

you could also do this:

alter your asp.net-file

```
<!-- add enctype=...  -->
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ... 
    <!-- add name=... -->
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="showMyImage(this)" name="uploadImage" />
    ...
```

in the Codebehind:

```
HttpPostedFile imageFile= Request.Files["uploadImage"];

if (imageFile && imageFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
   // ... Use the imageFile variable as you please
}
```

Which **Option** depends, what you want to do with the data.

Comment: .val is not working but this give me another idea to use hiddenfield.

Comment: what you mean `val` is not working. javascript error? or the field is has no value, or...? please, be a bit more specific.

Comment: val is not available for image I mean val is not an attribute.

Comment: `val()` is set on a hidden input-field `<input class="image-data" type="hidden" id="imageString" runat="server" />`. Then on the Server you read the data from that hidden field, NOT the image. `string imageData = imageString.Value;`

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply but I used asp:hidden control. But your suggested option is also right..Thank you so much for this idea.